# How to check if contenteditable div contain only spaces jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to prevent users from submit posts that contain only spaces so i try something like trim but i failed.

How can detect if contenteditable div contain only spaces?

```
if(text.replace(/\n/g, "") =="" || jQuery.trim(text) == 0) {
    var is_empty = 'true';
}
```

Comment: How about `if(text.trim() === "") return;` ?

Comment: @HamidMosalla I think you mean if(jQuery.trim(text) === "") but it's also not working.

Comment: `trim()` works on any string, it doesn't need jQuery...

Comment: @HamidMosalla I understand but it's not working please check again and let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("shit").addEventListener("click",function() {
    var is_empty = document.getElementById("contentEditable").innerText.trim() == ""
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = is_empty
})
```

```html
<div id="contentEditable" contenteditable="true">I am not empty</div>
<input type="button" id="shit" value="check"><p id="result"></p>
```

as of what Hamid Mosalla says, trimming the innerText of the content editable will solve your problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/8Lzrcc2n/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not working are you already try it? when i submit only spaces it's give me false.

Comment: Will you give me an example of the contenteditable div and your scripts? i'll try to review it and solve the problem @sadadadadasdad

Comment: I understand now your code is checking if contenteditable div is empty or not but it's checking for letters not spaces so when i try to submit only spaces without letter it's give me false, I hope you understand me i need to check if contenteditable div have spaces only without letters or not.

Comment: You can check this on facebook to understand me more, On facebook if you write only spaces it's give you alert "This post appears to be blank. Please write something or attach a link or photo to post."

Comment: @sadadadadasdad the contenteditable uses different kind of space, check the snippet above. it works

Comment: @sadadadadasdad updated my answer. probably the best solution :)